# Javascript Node.js overwrite File completely

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs, writefile

i have an application which needs a `data.json` file in order to draw a d3-graph. However i need to update that file on an `onClick`-Event:

```
d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
        try{
            $.get('https://localhost:4444/data', function(data) {
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
```

Above is the update-Button with the jquery-call. In my `app.js` File I am using it like this:

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
    try{
        getJSON();
}
catch(e) {
    alert('Error');
    }
```

});

The `getJSON()`-Function is received Data over an https-Request, processes that data and saves it to `data.json`:

```
function getJSON() {
      var req = https.get(options, function(response) {
    // handle the response
    var res_data = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        res_data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        //process data
        // save to file
        fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(finalJson), function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        });
    });
});
}
```

However if i click on my `updateButton` repeatedly after seconds, it seems that `data.json` is not overwritten but the file gets bigger and bigger, means that data is added to the file instead of overwritten.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use app.get as your route, I guess you are using express.

In your routes definition:

```
var getData = (function() {

    var callbacks = [];

    function executeCallbacks(err, data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            callbacks[i](err, data);
        }
        callbacks = [];
    }

    return function(cb) {
        callbacks.push(cb);

        if( callbacks.length === 1 ) {

            var req = https.get(options, function(response) {

                // handle the response
                var res_data = '';

                response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    res_data += chunk;
                });

                response.once('end', function() {

                    // process data here

                    // save to file
                    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(finalJson), function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            // call error handler
                            return executeCallbacks(err);
                        }

                        executeCallbacks(null, body);
                    });
                });

                response.once('error', function() {
                    return executeCallbacks(err);
                });
            }

            req.end();
        }
    };
})();



app.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {

    getData(function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        return data;
    });

});
```

In your browser js file:

```
d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
    $.get( 'https://localhost:4444/data', function(data) {
        alert( "success" );
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
    })
   .fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );
   });
});
```

I see you use try / catch around callback functions. The callback function fires after the original function completes. So don't use Try / Catch around callback function.

Read: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/

Comment: It seems to me @dnkss23 wants to fetch a file from somewhere else, and store it on the server. Not post the data from the browser at all. Why the data needs to be stored intermediately on the server, I don't know.

Comment: That can be done on the server alone, you don't need the browser for that. Best to use Request or something like that on the server.

Comment: yes @LinusGustavLarssonThiel is right! I want to load the data from somewhere else and save it on the server. However the saved file gets not overwritten but the content is added to the existing file. Why?

Comment: @blablabla But i want the user to be able to update the data manually by a button-click-event. So I do need the browser, right? I tried your solution, but it does not fix the 'Overwrite-Problem' and i get an additional error:'Can't set headers after they are sent.'

Comment: From your example, it makes no sense at all. My guess is that there is something happening in "// process data" in the example.

Comment: "//process data" is just transforming the received data from the https request in `getJSON()` and save it to `data.json`. And with `data.json` I am  building a d3-graph.... In order to keep the d3-graph updated, I want to update `data.json`. What I don't understand is, that `getJSON()` (receiving, transforming and store data) works just fine if i execute it by it's own in a seperate file. But as soon as I am using it within the Server and the UpdateButton-Click-Event It does not overwrite 'data.json' but adds content to the existing file. Do you understand now?  @LinusGustavLarssonThiel

Comment: In the documentation they execute req.end(). Maybe you should too. Otherwise the request stays open I guess. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: Why don't you use Request library? It makes calls like this a lot easier. https://github.com/request/request

Comment: @blablabla I don't think that you understand my problem.... The https-Request just works fine, that's not the problem(btw: I am already using req.end()! My Problem is the part where I write the File. fs.writeFile is not overwriting the existing file....

Comment: You are not using the req.end() in the getJSON function

Comment: I think the problem is because you don't check if a https request is already in progress, it does it twice (or more) at the same time. For each call to the /data route.

Comment: @blablabla ok, my fault. I missed to copy the req.end() in my example above, but it's in my code! Your guess, could be the problem... Even though I don't really know why it has to be checked....
How do I check whether a request is in process or not?